# MigrationBuilder.InsertData not working in old migration

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I have a database table in MySQL called thing_type which has 'name' and 'description' columns.

I have an old 'initial migration' generated by a previous version of Entity Framework that seeds this table like this

```
migrationBuilder.InsertData(
        table: "thing_type",
        columns: new[] { "name", "description" },
        values: new object[] { "SomeName", "Some description" });
```

The corresponding class is called ThingType and it has properties: Name and Description (the first letter of each is uppercase). It looks like this

```
[Table("thing_type")]
public class ThingType
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(45), Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(255), Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Now, after upgrading to EFCore 6, if I wipe the database, the seeding fails with this error

```
There is no property mapped to the column 'thing_type.name' which is used in a data operation. Either add a property mapped to this column, or specify the column types in the data operation.'
```

I've tried adding [Column("name")] to the property but with no luck. With an existing database, everything seems to run fine even without the column attribute so it just seems to be the seeding operation that has a problem.

The problematic lines in the existing migration look like this

```
  migrationBuilder.InsertData(
    table: "thing_type",
    columns: new[] { "name", "description" },
    values: new object[] { "Some name", "Some description" });
```

If I manually edit the migration to remove the insert operations, I can get past the error but then I don't have the seed data.

I can replace the above line with a manual SQL insert instead like this

```
migrationBuilder.Sql("INSERT INTO thing_type (name, description) VALUES ('Some name', 'Some description')");
```

...and that works, but I don't like editing an existing migration and it doesn't feel right.

Update: in our designer file for the migration that's failing after upgrading to EFCore6, we have this sort of thing:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity("A.B.C.ThingType", b =>
        {
            ...

            b.Property<string>("Description");

            b.Property<string>("Name");

            ...

            b.ToTable("thing_type");
        });
```

I'm guessing we now need a .HasColumnName("name") which is still a change I would rather not have to make since we have not had to do this before now. It does seem as though something has changed since the migration was created.

Thanks

Comment: It's worth including the `ThingType` class and related fluent configuration, including the `.HasData` call which generates the `.InsertData` migration call.

Comment: Bu still I don't see the **seeding** call (`.HasData`). See, the error message says "*There is no **property** mapped to the **column** 'thing_type.name'*". The raw SQL proves that you have **column**, so the problem should be with **property**. That's why we need to see that code.

Comment: We don't actually have a call to HasData() in our DB context. I can see that HasData would be the current way to seed data but when our migrations were created I think it just added those calls to migrationBuilder.InsertData to the migration code itself. I think the migration was created with EF Core 2.6. Does that sound plausible?

Comment: Hmm, so you are actually modifying generated migrations :-/ `InsertData` is intended to be generated by `HasData` fluent API, so it must have existed at the time you created the migration. Anyway, looks like you have changed the casing of property and/or column names. Take a look at the designer.cs file for that migration and see if it contains `b.Property<string>("Name")` or `b.Property<string>("name")` for that entity. The `InsertData` should use that name (exact casing).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I've updated the question with some extra info about our designer files. There's no attempt to use the lowercase column name so maybe at some point our model/table has changed in the past (I'll dig and try to find out)